# Site Title Doesn't Stay Centered When Browser Window is Shrunk

Tags: html, css

When the browser window is shrunk the site title goes to the bottom of the navigation window instead of staying centered in it.

Question: Does anybody know how I can have the site title remain centered in my navigation bar until the browser window is small enough that it goes above the list items as I want it to?

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyersAN/oupkw4uv/

The HTML code for the site title is:

```
<span><a href="index.html" class="logo" id="home">Hyperdog Productions</a></span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could not reproduce the issue (Chrome 45.0 on Mac OS X 10.10)

Comment: did the problem not display in jsfiddle?

Comment: vertical align: middle to .navbar_list should help out I guess, if I understood correctly that is

Comment: Your JSFiddle already works as you want it to on my system.

Comment: on mine, that logo, collapses down on larger screens @Kwarrtz

Comment: @Crispy-George it worked, thank you very much!!!

Comment: no problem, glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

I went into the fiddle and changed the styles for .logo to:

```
.logo {
    font-family: "PT-Sans", "Calibri Light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 8px 8px 8px #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #AF7817;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

I got rid of the `position: absolute;` stuff and added `vertical-align: bottom;`